# Install Firefox addon programmatically?

Tags: firefox-addon

I want to install a Firefox addon to the browser from desktop application. I'm using C#. I copied the `.xpi` file to extension folder of default profile. But Firefox does not recognize that addon when I restart Firefox.

I read a [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry) on the Mozilla website. But it's very unclear. Even there is no registry like `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions`. I think it's outdated .

Question: if extension `id=12345678` and name is `myaddon` how can I add my extension to windows registry so firefox will recognize new addon when restart .my default profile folder is `C:\Users\piumi.baby\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\d32m6v0j.default`

Comment: have you found any useful solution?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using the [mozilla firefox command line statements?](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments)

Let me know if that helped. 
I've successfully launched an .XPI file install using the following command line options:

firefox.exe -install -extension path_to_extension. Of course, the used had to agree with the installation (this was according to my scenario)