# Install firefox addon programmatically

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I've asked this question on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1180020/install-firefox-addon-programmatically).

Someone has asked a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607845/install-firefox-addon-programatically) on stackoverflow.

Neither question has been answered. The `-install` flag to the firefox executable referenced in the 2014 answer appears to have been deprecated.

I'm using the following script to download extensions into a profile's `extensions` directory from a provided list of xpi urls:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

ABSOLUTE_PATH="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)/$(basename "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"
ADDONS_LIST="$(dirname ${ABSOLUTE_PATH})/addons.list"

PROFILE_DIR="${1}"
test -n "${PROFILE_DIR}" || exit 1

EXTENSIONS_DIR="${PROFILE_DIR}/extensions"
test -d "${EXTENSIONS_DIR}" || mkdir "${EXTENSIONS_DIR}"

cd "${EXTENSIONS_DIR}"
for URL in $(cut -d: -f2- < ${ADDONS_LIST}); do
    XPI_URL=$(curl -LIs ${URL} | grep Location | cut -d' ' -f2- \
             | sed 's/?.*//')
    FILENAME=$(basename ${XPI_URL})
    curl -s "${XPI_URL}" -o "${FILENAME}"
done
```

I've also tried placing the xpis under `~/.mozilla/extensions`, `~/.mozilla/DEFAULT-PROFILE/extensions`. But upon restarting firefox and going to the addons page, the page is empty, and I still have to manually find and install the XPI files.

Comment: Are you naming the *.xpi* file correctly, based on the add-on ID in the *install.rdf*, or *manifest.json*? Copying the extension's *.xpi* file into the `<profile_directory>/extensions`, with the correct file name (which is not, necessarily, the name used in downloading) *does* work. I done this *many* times. A tab should come up, the next time the profile is used, asking for authorization to install the extension.

Comment: the filename of the xpi, not matching the id in install.rdf, was the problem. would you mind adding your comment as an answer?

Comment: I'm glad that solved your problem. I was recalling that I had supplied a more complete answer to installing by copying the file in a couple of other answers. I needed to go searching for them and re-read them to verify I had actually covered the issue, which I did. I didn't have the time to look around when I left the comment. So, instead of posting an answer here, I'm going to propose a duplicate. There's nothing wrong with this being a duplicate. Duplicates help people find the information, which clearly is needed based on you not finding it.

Comment: if it's a `manifest.json`, how do I determine the xpi filename?

Comment: The linked duplicate-target question explains that the ID is in `applications.gecko.id` in the *manifest.json*. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/applications).

Comment: I have a `manifest.json` without an `applications.gecko.id`. Is this an invalid manifest? Specifically it is https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disconnect/